# problem in fetching data from tables of sql in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

hi i"ve created multiples tables in sql first time s i'm having difficulties in fetching data. so here is my code ,

```
<?php

// Use to fetch product data
class Product
{
    public $db = null;

    public function __construct(DBController $db)
    {
        if (!isset($db->con)) return null;
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    // fetch product data using getData Method
    public function getData($table = 'lipstick', $liner = 'liner', $brush = 'brush', $eyeshadow = 'eyeshadow'){
        $result = $this->db->con->query( "SELECT * FROM {$table}");
        $result1 = $this->db->con->query( "SELECT * FROM {$liner}");
        
        
        $result2 = $this->db->con->query("SELECT * FROM {$eyeshadow}");
        $result3 = $this->db->con->query("SELECT * FROM {$brush}");
                                                                    

        $resultArray = array();

        // fetch product data one by one
        while ($item = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            $resultArray[] = $item;
        }

        return $resultArray;
    }
```

i'm only getting data from $result as i want to fetch data from $result 1-3.

i tried to run loop for all the result variables like this,

```
<?php

// Use to fetch product data
class Product
{
    public $db = null;

    public function __construct(DBController $db)
    {
        if (!isset($db->con)) return null;
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    // fetch product data using getData Method
    public function getData($table = 'lipstick', $liner = 'liner', $brush = 'brush', $eyeshadow = 'eyeshadow'){
        $result = $this->db->con->query( "SELECT * FROM {$table}");
        $result1 = $this->db->con->query( "SELECT * FROM {$liner}");
        
        
        $result2 = $this->db->con->query("SELECT * FROM {$eyeshadow}");
        $result3 = $this->db->con->query("SELECT * FROM {$brush}");
                                                                    

        $resultArray = array();

        // fetch product data one by one
        while ($item = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            $resultArray[] = $item;
        }

        return $resultArray;

          // fetch product data one by one
          while ($item1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            $resultArray[] = $item1;
        }

        return $resultArray;
          // fetch product data one by one
          while ($item2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            $resultArray[] = $item2;
        }

        return $resultArray;
          // fetch product data one by one
          while ($item3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            $resultArray[] = $item3;
        }

        return $resultArray;
    }
```

but i got the error which was ::undefined variable item1-3 in line no 74::
what should i do now.

Comment: When you find yourself numbering variables like `$result1/2/3` you likely need an array instead. When you find yourself writing several identical blocks of code in a row like `while($item = ...) { ... }` you probably need a loop instead. When you find yourself trying to wrangle 4 identical query result sets you might need a `UNION` instead. When you have 4 identical tables differentiated only by name you probably have a schema design and/or normalization issue.

Comment: a database is relational, so you could join/ union them in qnoe query

Comment: Also, the reason you are not getting the results of 1,2,3 is that , after running a loop over `$result` you are returning your array, so the next code is unreachable..

Comment: Question lacks fundamental understanding of programming.

Comment: Vishal Kamlapure , thanks for helping basically i'm learning over myself i've no teacher the only teacher i've is YouTube so i get confused several time or i get stuck so i tried to communicate with experts .

Answer (score 0):

You have some mistakes in your code, i somekind of "corrected" your code for you.

1. return statement exits your function means code below return is not executed
2. you can reuse variables
3. use multidimensional array to store multiple tables in one array

I know its not the best way to query the database - but i hope it helps you a little

```
public function getData($table = 'lipstick', $liner = 'liner', $brush = 'brush', $eyeshadow = 'eyeshadow'){
    $result = $this->db->con->query( "SELECT * FROM {$table}");
    $result1 = $this->db->con->query( "SELECT * FROM {$liner}");
    $result2 = $this->db->con->query("SELECT * FROM {$eyeshadow}");
    $result3 = $this->db->con->query("SELECT * FROM {$brush}");
                                                                    

    $resultArray = array();

    // fetch product data one by one
    $resultArray[$table] = array();
    while ($item = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        array_push($resultArray[$table], $item);
    }

    //return $resultArray;          //no return here, if you return here the code below will not be executed

    // fetch product data one by one
    $resultArray[$liner] = array();
    while ($item = mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){     
        array_push($resultArray[$liner], $item);                            
    }

    //return $resultArray;          //no return here, if you return here the code below will not be executed
    // fetch product data one by one
    $resultArray[$eyeshadow] = array();
    while ($item = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){     
        array_push($resultArray[$eyeshadow], $item);                                
    }

    //return $resultArray;          //no return here, if you return here the code below will not be executed
    // fetch product data one by one
    $resultArray[$brush] = array();
    while ($item = mysqli_fetch_array($result3, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){     //you can reuse $item
        array_push($resultArray[$brush], $item);                                
    }

    return $resultArray;
}
```